# Set of accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

I have this topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ :$$\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\Omega_n,~n\geq 0\}$$

where $$\Omega_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x|\geq n\}$$

I want to find the set of accumulation points of the point $(2,-2)$ denoted by $\{(2,-2)\}'$

first I found the closure with is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\Omega_3$

Then I found that $\{(2,-2)\}'=[\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\Omega_3] \setminus\{(2,-2)\}$

I'm right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The closure is correct. It’s the smallest closed set that contains $(-2,2)$. As a consequence the set of limit points is also correct, because in any space $\{x\}’=\overline{\{x\}}\setminus \{x\}$, as $x$ cannot be a limit point of $\{x\}$ by definition, and all limit points lie in the closure.

Comment: than the point $(2,-2)$ is an isolated point right ?

Comment: @PolineSandra no it is not. It’s not an open singleton.

Comment: but how? so it is an accumulation point ? we say that  $a$ is isolated in A if there exists a neighborhood $V$  of a such that $V\cap A=\{a\}$

Comment: @PolineSandra no, $x$ is isolated in $\{x\}$, always. And it’s never a limit point of it. But neither an accumulation point ( in most definitions of this term).